# How do I find the remote IP address for a Go http.Response?

Tags: http, go

The http.Request struct includes the remote IP and port of the request's sender:

```
    // RemoteAddr allows HTTP servers and other software to record
    // the network address that sent the request, usually for
    // logging. This field is not filled in by ReadRequest and
    // has no defined format. The HTTP server in this package
    // sets RemoteAddr to an "IP:port" address before invoking a
    // handler.
    // This field is ignored by the HTTP client.
    **RemoteAddr string**
```

The http.Response object has no such field.

I would like to know the IP address that responded to the request I sent, even when I sent it to a DNS address.

I thought that net.LookupHost() might be helpful, but 1) it can return multiple IPs for a single host name, and 2) it ignores the hosts file unless cgo is available, which it is not in my case.

Is it possible to retrieve the remote IP address for an http.Response?

Comment: @B.Adler that question is asking about an http.Request.  I am asking about an http.Response.

Comment: The best way is to have the server include it in a header. In many cases you won't even be connecting directly to the server, and the address would only be known by the proxy or load balancer.

Comment: Your should clarify early in your question that you are writing an HTTP *client*.

Comment: @JimB I don't control the server.

Comment: @dolmen my question says "to the request I sent", which makes me the client.

Comment: @B.Adler again, I am looking for the remote address in an http.Response, not in an http.Request

Comment: Use the [net/http/httptrace](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace) package and use the [`GotConnInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/#GotConnInfo) hook to capture the `net.Conn` and its corresponding `Conn.RemoteAddr`

Comment: some comments here are past & beyond what the OP asked ... ? @JimB he wants to know what host the client is connecting to itfp . AND: How is it not clear that he is on the client side: "I would like to know the IP address that responded to the request I sent"

Comment: What is misleading in the OP here is that the Request field is mentioned (while typically a request only specifies a target URL, prior determined what connection will be used for this host). The request field mentioned here is indeed for server side usage only. A client can only meaningfully embrace notion of remote connection when response is being received obviously.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [net/http/httptrace](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace) package and use the [`GotConnInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/#GotConnInfo) hook to capture the `net.Conn` and its corresponding `Conn.RemoteAddr()`.

This will give you the address the `Transport` actually dialled, as opposed to what was resolved in [`DNSDoneInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/#DNSDoneInfo):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptrace"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example.com/", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: func(connInfo httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
            log.Printf("resolved to: %s", connInfo.Conn.RemoteAddr())
        },
    }

    req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace))

    client := &http.Client{}
    _, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
~ go run ip.go
2017/02/18 19:38:11 resolved to: 104.16.xx.xxx:443
```

Comment: to improve this already valid answer: the term "resolved" is misleading here. the hook traces either connection "used" by the client for a specific request (thus its response) transmission. Connections may be re-used for several requests (see pipelining in HTTP 1.1) and even in parallel (HTTP2) from eithers client pool (ie see DialContext etc).

Answer (score -1):

Another solution I came up with was the hook the `DialContext` function in the http client transport. This is a specific solution that lets you modify the `http.Client` instead of the request which may be useful.

We first create a function that returns a hooked dial context

```
func remoteAddressDialHook(remoteAddressPtr *net.Addr) func(ctx context.Context, network string, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
    hookedDialContext := func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
        originalDialer := &net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        }

        conn, err := originalDialer.DialContext(ctx, network, address)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // conn was successfully created
        *remoteAddressPtr = conn.RemoteAddr()
        return conn, err
    }

    return hookedDialContext
}
```

We can then use this function to create a `DialContext` that writes to an outparameter

```
    var remoteAddr net.Addr
    customTransport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy:                 http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        DialContext:           remoteAddressDialHook(&remoteAddr),
        ForceAttemptHTTP2:     true,
        MaxIdleConns:          100,
        IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }
    customHttpClient := http.Client{
        Transport: customTransport,
    }

    // do what you normally would with a http client, it will then set the remoteAddr to be the remote address
    fmt.Println(remoteAddr.String())
```

Comment: How can that approach even work with HTTP2, or either HTTP 1.1 keep-alive connection modes. If you only hook into DialContext, it gets only called on new dials - but how do you map the pool items to either response ? :) I think trace package does this properly and you shouldnt mislead people with halfbaked solutions probably. DialContext is to provide own connection pool, but is not suitable for tracing connection usage against client one.